# How to remove all plugins from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How do I delete all plugins on wordpress? the layout is different now. It used to be really simple. please help!

Comment: The Wordpress codex may help you there: https://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Uninstalling_Plugins

Answer (score 1):

Delete everything inside `wp-content/plugins/`

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way to delete any plugin is to go to the plugin page from your admin panel, select the plugins you don't want to use by selecting the checkbox beside the name of the plugin and deactivate them by selecting the bulk action option on the top of the pane. Once you deactivate the plugins then follow the same procedure but now for bulk action choose to move to trash. You can delete it permanently also by selecting trash and delete it permanently.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable your plugin from wordpress admin side plugin section, disable all plugin one by one and check your layout is proper now or not, or you can simply disable all plugin using your FTP, change folder name inside wp-contents/plugins to something like /oldplugins. and whenever you need it back simply rename the plugin folder as it is.